# Can I write "our patented solution" for patent pending?

Tags: patent-pending

My boss wants me to use that phrase, but I'm reluctant as "patented" infers that the technology has already been granted a patent, whereas "patent pending" which is clearer. I referred to our technology as "patent pending" numerous times in a document. To reduce the repetition, they want me to refer to our technology as "patented" later on. E.g.:

> Our patent-pending technology empowers your business to ____.
>   [...] (several paragraphs later) Moreover, with our patent-pending technology, you can ____. [...] (two sentences later) Our patented technology enables ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct.

Once you file a patent application you have a "patent pending," and therefore you can use that language.

You should not say "our patented technology" unless a patent has actually been issued.

If getting a patent issued rapidly is very important to you, there are numerous ways to speed up the process.